# Error: Unknown type name

Tags: c

I'm new to modular programming and I hope you can help me out :)
So here are my .c .h:
item.h

```
#define L 31
#define L1 11
typedef struct{
    int priority;
    char service_type[L];
    char client_code[L1];
}*Item;
Item New_client();
```

item.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "item.h"
Item New_client(){
    Item new_c=malloc(sizeof new_c);
    printf("Inserire priorita': "); scanf("%d",&new_c->priority);
    printf("Inserire servizio: "); scanf("%s",new_c->service_type);
    printf("Inserire codice cliente: "); scanf("%s",new_c->client_code);
    return new_c;
}
```

PQ.h

```
typedef struct Nodo *link;
struct Nodo{
    Item item;
    link next;
};
void init(link coda);
int empty_(link coda);
link insert_(link h,Item client);
```

PQ.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "PQ.h"
```

So as I include PQ.h in PQ.c I get the error: unknown type name 'Item' from CodeBlocks... I can't figure why and what can I do to solve the problem.

Comment: Note also that `malloc(sizeof new_c)` should be `malloc(sizeof *new_c)`.

Comment: Yes you're right thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include `item.h` in your `PQ.h`:

```
#include "item.h"

typedef struct Nodo *link;
struct Nodo{
    Item item;
    link next;
};
void init(link coda);
int empty_(link coda);
link insert_(link h,Item client);
```

**Update**: about *error: conflicting types for 'Item'*
This becouse preprocessor include `item.h` twice. You should wrap header with `#ifndef __HEADER_NAME__`, `#define __HEADER_NAME__`, `#endif` combination. See how it can be done for item.h:

```
#ifndef __ITEM_H__
#define __ITEM_H__

#define L 31
#define L1 11
typedef struct{
    int priority;
    char service_type[L];
    char client_code[L1];
}*Item;
Item New_client();

#endif //__ITEM_H__
```

Comment: If I do that I get the error: conflicting types for 'Item'

Comment: Thanks man you solved my problem! But why do I need to include item.h in PQ.h? The typedef Item is a global declaration so why PQ.h doesn't see it?

Comment: @Andrea `typedef` is not a global declaration, its assigning name `Item` to the structure. In each header/source files where you use `Item` you should include appropriate header.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks again SergA.